# c# MVC best way to make use of AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In terms of making a an AJAX call, we have use the following method:

```
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             async: false,
             url: '@Url.Action("CheckPhone", "Progg")',
             data: { input: WebPhoneNum
             },
             success: function (iReturn) {
                 if (iReturn == 0) {
                     alert(Phone Number must be in format (XXX) XXX-XXXX. Please Re-Enter');
                     submitval = false;
                 }
             },
             error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                 var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); // Boil the ASP.NET AJAX error down to JSON.                    
                 alert('Call to CheckPhone failed with error:  ' + err.Message); // display the error raised by the server
             }
         });
```

Notice how it makes a call to the controller and returns a value. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. I know .NET MVC has some ajax calls built in but couldn't find one that fits what I am doing below. I know .NET MVC has a ajax call build that with a hyperlink but that is not what I need. I just need to make a call to the controller that returns some value(s).

THanks

Comment: may be better place is code review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one thing that you need to fix:

```
async: false
```

must become:

```
async: true
```

because otherwise you are not doing AJAX. You are sending a synchronous request to the server freezing the client browser.

Other than that you seem to be doing some remote validation with this AJAX request. You probably might take a look at the [`[Remote]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute that's built in and which avoids you writing all this code. All you need to do is decorate the view model property that needs to be validated with this attribute and then enable unobtrusive client side validation by including the proper scripts.

Comment: Hi Darin, I am familiar with REMOTE. What if I like to return say a JSON object. Remote may not work for that as from my understanding it returns a true/false.

Comment: If it is for validation purposes why do you need to return a JSON object? How do you intend to use it? You haven't provided any context about what you are trying to achieve and yet you are asking for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

try to validate the format of a input with ajax?
I recommend you learn about data annotations to validate that kind of details (please revalidate on server at submit form like a good practice)

here is a usefull tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs